# Rollup amount avg

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, rollup

I've table EMP  that is joined with other table; EMP has empname and emplength (in months) like this

```
'A' 100
'B' 110
'D' 80
'E' 120
```

I'm calculating avg length per year i.e dividing by 12 for each employee and overall. Here the question is how to calculate for the overall avg amount by using rollup?

output should be like this

```
'A' 8.33
'B' 9.16
'D' 6.66
'E' 10.00
total 8.54
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `ROLLUP` for this scenario. You can achieve this using `UNION ALL` like following.

```
select name, [length] / 12.0
from yourtable
union all
select 'Total', avg(length/12.0)
from yourtable
```

But still if you want to use `ROLLUP`, you can try like following.

```
select name , avg([length])
from
(
    select name, [length] / 12.0 as [length]
    from yourtable
    cross join
    (
     values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
    ) t(a)
) t
group by  rollup(name)
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/QUP14087)

Comment: Thank you yes we can do like this also but am rollup for other fields also

Comment: Thank you; but why cross join?

Comment: when you want to use ROLLUP for average without union, you can use only one aggregate, so i have change 1 row to 12 rows and did a avg.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grouping sets`:

```
select coalesce(empname, total) as empname, avg(emplength)
from . . .
group by grouping sets (empname, ());
```